# How to reduce points by proximity

Tags: qgis, density, proximity

I got a layer with over 4 million points. The distance between the points are 1 meter.

How can i reduce the data so that no points have less than e.g. 10 meters between them?

Comment: I believe you can use the DBScan algorithm for this, ie, producing clusters that are separated by x-distance. There is certainly a scikit-learn (Python) implementation, but I have no idea about QGIS.

Comment: Could you explain a bit more about why you want to do this? Throwing data away is rarely a good step - but perhaps analysing and creating a new (simpler / smaller) layer by a spatial join is better?

Comment: The points consists of XYZ-data and is used to produce a mesh. The huge amount of point are heavy to work with and the mesh polygons will not be less than about 5 or 10 meter.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe is not the fastest way but you could achieve this in three steps:

Convert your points to raster:
Raster -> Conversion -> Rasterize

Reduce the resolution:
Raster -> Conversion -> Translate (Outsize)

Convert your resized raster back to points again using the SAGA pluguin. Algorithm -> Grid values to points.

However, I'm still not sure about what you want to accomplish, as @Simbamangu said usually it is not a good idea just to eliminate data. Maybe you need to average, sum, interpolate...

Answer (score 3):

In the top toolbar: Vector > Shape Tools > Geodesic Geometry Simplification > Geodesic point decimate. You can then specify the input layer, specify the minimum distance between points, and save the output layer in specified directory.

[image]

Comment: To add: **Shape Tools** is a plugin, so you need it installed first